# How do I match phpseclib1 Rijndael.php CBC AES encryption in golang?

Tags: php, go, cryptography, aes

I am encrypting like:

```
  plaintextstr := "0000000000000thankustackoverflow"
  plaintext := []byte(plaintextstr)

  key := []byte("abcdefghijklmnop")
  block, _ := aes.NewCipher(key)

  ciphertext := make([]byte, aes.BlockSize+len(plaintext))
  iv := ciphertext[:aes.BlockSize]

  mode := cipher.NewCBCEncrypter(block, iv)
  mode.CryptBlocks(ciphertext[aes.BlockSize:], plaintext)
  fmt.Printf("%x\n", ciphertext)
```

and the output is:

00000000000000000000000000000000d77aa6646bb541808ed23c88d4b06d30f42b01d6e806a02b29086bc82892334f

but the output from another version of this code writen in PHP is:

d77aa6646bb541808ed23c88d4b06d30f42b01d6e806a02b29086bc82892334fbf21ea861abbc3d72e44731978bb76c2

Notice the 00000000000000000000000000000000 is the exact length of the missing data at the end. And it's 32, the size of the orig plaintextstr. Any idea how to left shift all that in golang and get the missing data?

PHP:

```
<?php

include('Crypt/AES.php');

$aes = new Crypt_AES();

$aes->setKey('abcdefghijklmnop');
echo bin2hex($aes->encrypt("0000000000000thankustackoverflow"));
```

https://github.com/andrewarrow/phpseclib1/blob/master/Crypt/AES.php
https://github.com/andrewarrow/phpseclib1/blob/master/Crypt/Rijndael.php

Debug php output:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000 <--- IV
30303030303030303030303030746861 block 0
d77aa6646bb541808ed23c88d4b06d30 crypted 0
6e6b75737461636b6f766572666c6f77 block 16
f42b01d6e806a02b29086bc82892334f crypted 16
10101010101010101010101010101010 block 32
bf21ea861abbc3d72e44731978bb76c2 crypted 32
```

Comment: fmt.Printf("%x\n", ciphertext[aes.BlockSize:])

Comment: The output ciphertext from Go seems to be decrypt correctly back to the original plain text. See [here](https://play.golang.org/p/LmL4N1J0Aq). Can't say same for php ciphertext

Comment: php info https://gist.github.com/andrewarrow/2cb9484a3d0f0f7f1db24660e406a755

Comment: full source https://github.com/Marfjeh/ALA-Reken/blob/c1c8926648ab33b1320c3b4d63c60d4a9c73de56/src/phpmyadmin/libraries/phpseclib/Crypt/Rijndael.php

Comment: better link https://github.com/andrewarrow/phpseclib1/blob/master/Crypt/AES.php

Comment: i updated the question with example php code to show problem.

Comment: Again, I am asking to use an explicit for the IV so it can be distinguished from 0x00 bytes. That will show if the IV is prefixing the encrypted data for the Go case.

Comment: by explicit iv do you mean adding something like "io.ReadFull(bytes.NewReader([]byte{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}), iv)" ? So I tried that and get very different output: 0102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f10b2439c71f018c42cfae730f9a9c49a4584c2e432dcc6e06fac5d13d1b39aeb11

Comment: Yes, and you will get a different output, that is the point of an IV, which should be a random value so that the same message wil lnot have the same encrypted data. As you can see the IV is sent prefixed to the encrypted data, that is used for the IV when decrypting.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a shifting problem, it is an output buffer size problem due to the prefixing of the iv to the encrypted data.

The IV is a block of nulls (0x00) since it is never set to a value. It is prepended to the encrypted data, that is common. A block of padding needs to be added since the input data is an exact multiple of the block size.

This the output buffer needs to be the size of the iv + the size of the data + the size of the padding block. (16 + 32 + 16 = 64)

Add another block size to the output buffer:

```
ciphertext := make([]byte, aes.BlockSize + len(plaintext) + aes.BlockSize)
```

Comment: i get more zeros on the end, but still don't get the missing data php has.

Comment: i updated the question with example php code to show problem

Answer (score -1):

The PHP version was encoding an extra 16 bytes of an "empty" string that was filled with 16s!

```
  p1 := "0000000000000tha"
  p2 := "nkustackoverflow"

  p1b := []byte(p1)
  p2b := []byte(p2)
  p3b, _ := hex.DecodeString("10101010101010101010101010101010")
  fmt.Println(p3b)

  key := []byte("abcdefghijklmnop")
  block, _ := aes.NewCipher(key)
  ciphertext := make([]byte, aes.BlockSize+16)
  iv := ciphertext[:aes.BlockSize]
  mode := cipher.NewCBCEncrypter(block, iv)

  i := 0
  for {
    if i == 0 {
      mode.CryptBlocks(ciphertext[aes.BlockSize:], p1b)
    } else if i == 1 {
      mode.CryptBlocks(ciphertext[aes.BlockSize:], p2b)
    } else if i == 2 {
      mode.CryptBlocks(ciphertext[aes.BlockSize:], p3b)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%x\n", ciphertext[16:])
    i += 1
    if i > 2 {
      break
    }
  }
```

This code prints the `identical` stuff in golang that php is.

Comment: That is [PKCS#7 padding](PKCS#7 padding). AES is a block cipher and required input to be in exact multiples of the block size, 16-bytes. Padding is needed when the input is not an exact multiple of the block size and when using padding every encryption must be padded which means adding padding even when the input is an exact multiple of the block. The padding bytes are the integer value of the number of padding bytes. In your case one block of padding is being added, 16 bytes, tyhat is why there are 16 bytes of padding with the value 16.